# Overflow-X not working in muli-column CSS grid layout

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I have a simple grid layout with 2 columns. Inside of the grid cells `overflow-x` seems to not be working. Is there any way to make this layout with working `overflow-x` inside of the cells?

[image: Wide element scrolls outside of grid but not inside]

```css
.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 1fr) auto;
  gap: 20px;
}

.main-grid>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

.main-grid>div>div {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.scroll-me {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.i-am-too-wide {
  width: 800px;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
  <div>
    <div>
      1
    </div>
    <div>
      2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      A
    </div>
    <div>
      B

      <div class="scroll-me">
        <div class="i-am-too-wide">
          Wide element inside grid
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="scroll-me margin-top">
  <div class="i-am-too-wide">
    WIDE element outside grid
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The column that will contain the overflow / scrollbar is set to `auto` width. This means that the length of the column is based on the length of the content. It also means that the column will shrink / expand based on the length of the content, and an overflow can never occur. You need to set a fixed length somewhere along the line so that an overflow can be triggered. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g1rzjeb8/1/)